# Why does `xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` give me 0x0 for some windows?

Tags: linux, xorg, window-manager, wayland

.. and what can I do about it?

When you try to get some information about the currently focused window you're often told to just run `xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` to get the window id of the currently active window.

But sometimes - e.g. when a terminal window is on top - I get `0x0` as result.

What is the reason and what can I do about it?

I'm using Fedora 25 (with Wayland)

Comment: what terminal are you using?  `xprop` will only work on clients of the Xwayland server (ie wayland's X11-compatibility layer), so if the only window showing is a pure-wayland client, `xprop` will not retrieve any info.

Comment: How can I find out whether it's a pure Wayland client? I used it on `terminator` and the Gnome terminal - both with same results..

Comment: GTK3 has a wayland backend now, and terminator is based on gnome-terminal, so i'd assume both are pure wayland by default.  you should be able to force it to the old backend with `GDK_BACKEND=x11` if you want.  other toolkits that support wayland: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/toolkits.html ... https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wayland#GUI_libraries ... so eg if you're running a QT4 application, you know it's Xwayland, but QT5 might be a pure wayland client.

Comment: Is there any alternative command that could work in pure-Xwayland context? (where instead `xprop` fails)